# How do I change an image with javascript without an onclick event?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get a dummy username and profile picture to display at random, at a random interval. I also want the usernames to match their respective profile pictures.

I currently I have html that displays the usernames correctly

`<p id="usr"></p>`
`<img id="changeimage" src="" alt="Profile picture">`

And javascript like this

```
var players = ['player1', 'player2', 'player3']
var playerpics = ['player1.jpg', 'player2.jpg', 'player3.jpg'];


var activeuser;
var playerpicker = function (activeuser) {
    usr.innerHTML = players[activeuser];
    changeimage.innerHTML = "<img src='" + playerpics[activeuser] + "' />";

};

setInterval(function () {
    var oneintwelve = Math.floor(Math.random() * 12);

    if (oneintwelve === 3) {
        activeuser = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
        playerpicker(activeuser);

    };
}, 1000);
```

I know I'm doing something wrong with implementing the new IMG tag, forgive me if I'm not doing this the best way, I'm fairly new to this. Thanks for the help.

Comment: `eval` is evil. `eval` is evil. `eval` is evil. `eval` is evil. `eval` is evil. `eval` is evil. `eval` is evil. ;(

Comment: @Allendar Without doubt you're right, but how is that evil related to the question? Or was it wiped out within the grace period?

Comment: instead changing with inner html, just fetch the image tag with javascript and change the src of the image like $('image').src='a.jpg'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there, you can change the src attribute of an image. Also you didn't quite correctly selected the elements.

```
var playerpicker = function (activeuser) {
    document.getElementById("usr").innerHTML = players[activeuser];
    document.getElementById("changeimage").src= playerpics[activeuser];
};
```

Check this link, it will help you learn http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_select.asp